# Hypothesis Testing - When to use which test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Does anyone know of a good, reliable website that lists the hypothesis tests (for population mean, population proportion, difference of means - I am in a first year stats course) along with their formulas? I am having a hard time wrapping my head around all the test and when to use them under certain conditions and knowing the associated formulas.

Comment: OK, after the edit the question sounds more realistic. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I find QUICKCALCS from Graphpad at https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ very helpful.
Other quite good introductions are
Daryl Huff's "How to lie with statistics" still in print
David M Lane's HyperStat Online Statistics Textbook at http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/index.html
and
NIST's Handbook of Engineering Statistics at https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/index.htm
You could also try asking your tutors to provide more advanced references applicable to the requirements of your particular course.